# How do I represent a component that is comprised of several files in a component diagram?

Tags: uml, diagram, artifacts, component-diagram

Since a single component could be manifested by multiple artifacts, I'd like to know how a component's multiple artifacts are represented in a component diagram. Or in other words if I have a component which is comprised by several files where the code of the whole component is implemented how can I draw the component diagram to make it clear the different files that comprise it?

Can I use a notation similar to a package where you can put the package symbol and inside the objects that the package contain? I mean, some sort of clickable component symbol where I double click and it opens showing the comprising files?

I use Enterprise Architect so examples using this will be even more helpful.

Regards!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Enterprise Architect, go to Component's properties (double click on the component box in the diagram) and go to files. That's the place to put the file list in Enterprise Architect.

Still, it's possible to model it in a way that a single file is represented as a separate component and thus "master" component is clickable so it is possible to navigate to another diagram, but when the model gets big and consists of many files it won't serve the purpose and it will get too complicated.

If for any reason, it is necessary to clearly mark the file list on the diagram, the note with textual description is sufficient.

Note that primarily a model (i.e. Component Diagram) is to show the parts of which the system is build and as opposite to the design, the file list is specific to the implementation.